# She being or her being

Tags: personal-pronouns

What sounds better here: 'she being....' or 'her being...', if both are not wrong?

1. She has a keen analytic mind and very good comprehension and communication skills. Her performance in examinations bears witness to the above, ***she being*** among the top five percent of her peer group.
2. She has a keen analytic mind and very good comprehension and communication skills. Her performance in examinations bears witness to the above, ***her being*** among the top five percent of her peer group

Comment: I would leave out "she" or "her". Unless you have a specific reason for adding it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally choose the first one,

> **she being**

as it emphasizes more on the her. **her being** would be better of in a context, where possession is required.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the main clause is "performance", not "she".

On the one hand, [there is reason to argue both ways](https://books.google.com/books?id=EXndBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=english+absolute+case&source=bl&ots=Pk2Z7DfQCU&sig=SY8kU_O47KYlDSBZnkjuOWxjZ14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOyv6tysPWAhWEYiYKHel1BlIQ6AEIfDAS#v=onepage&q=english%20absolute%20case&f=false) about the case of the personal pronoun in an absolute construction.  The choice between "she" and "her" can be reduced to a question of personal preference.  On the other hand, there is no reason to bring her (or she) back into the sentence.  The performance itself is the topic at hand.  That is to say:

> Her performance in examinations, among the top five percent of her peer group, bears witness to the above.

No need for "she".  No need for "being".  The prepositional phrase can carry the semantic weight on its own and lend that weight where it is most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these strike me as more preferable, as they both *sound* correct enough.

However, I would suggest that you have a third option, which sounds more natural to me:

> She has a keen analytic mind and very good comprehension and communication skills. Her performance in examinations bears witness to the above, ***with her being*** among the top five percent of her peer group.

Answer (score 0):

Neither sounds right; it's just a bad construction. I'd write

She has a keen analytic mind and very good comprehension and communication skills. Her performance in examinations bears witness to the above; she is among the top five percent of her peer group.